# iOS Convert Spacial character

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling one my private server api on that response i got some special chareter `"äÄääuÄuäuöÖöüÜ"`. But when i try to get in iOS they convert into `"Ã¤Ã„Ã¤Ã¤uÃ„uÃ¤uÃ¶Ã–Ã¶Ã¼Ã"`

But in postman got a perfect text `"äÄääuÄuäuöÖöüÜ"`.

Comment: what's api name?

Answer (score 1):

Encode the data using .utf8 encoding. By the way how is your api proving the response. You must provide the data as .utf8 encoding from your API side...